# How to convert java enum cases to swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have java enum classes and want to convert this in Swift language.
Below is my java enum case:

```
public enum BleCommandEnum {

GET_FIRST_VITAL((byte)0x11,    "Get first record of vital data", ""),
GET_NEXT_VITAL((byte)0x21, "Get next record of vital data", ""),
GET_PREV_VITAL((byte)0x31, "Get previous record of vital data", "");

}
```

Above code, I want to convert in swift language?
Please help.

Comment: That can't be the entire Java enum (it doesn't compile). Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an enum using tuple with `RawRepresentable`.

```
public enum BleCommandEnum: RawRepresentable{
    
    case GET_FIRST_VITAL
    case GET_NEXT_VITAL
    case GET_PREV_VITAL
    
    public init?(rawValue: (UInt8, String, String)) {
        switch rawValue {
        case (0x11, "Get first record of vital data", ""): self = .GET_FIRST_VITAL
        case (0x21, "Get next record of vital data", ""): self = .GET_NEXT_VITAL
        case (0x31, "Get previous record of vital data", ""): self = .GET_PREV_VITAL
        default: return nil
        }
    }
    
    public var rawValue: (UInt8, String, String) {
        switch self {
        case .GET_FIRST_VITAL: return (0x11, "Get first record of vital data", "")
        case .GET_NEXT_VITAL: return (0x21, "Get next record of vital data", "")
        case .GET_PREV_VITAL: return (0x31, "Get previous record of vital data", "")
        }
    }
}
```

Use :

```
let command = BleCommandEnum.GET_FIRST_VITAL
print(command.rawValue.0) //0x11
print(command.rawValue.1) //"Get first record of vital data"
print(command.rawValue.2) //""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare like this:

```swift
public enum BleCommandEnum: UInt8 {
    case GET_FIRST_VITAL = 0x11
    case GET_NEXT_VITAL = 0x21
    case GET_PREV_VITAL = 0x31
    
    var note: String {
        switch self {
        case .GET_FIRST_VITAL:
            return "Get first record of vital data"
        case .GET_NEXT_VITAL:
            return "Get next record of vital data"
        case .GET_PREV_VITAL:
            return "Get previous record of vital data"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about last parameter i.e. empty string?

Comment: actually, it depends on what you want to do with that parameter. You can just get the byte value like `BlueCommandEnum. GET_FIRST_VITAL.rawValue` and the description of itself with `BlueCommandEnum. GET_FIRST_VITAL.note`. No need to add any empty string here, I think :).